# React Navigation 5 Auth Flow

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my `React Native` app, I'm using `React Navigation 5` and trying to route users to authentication stack if the user is not authenticated i.e. there's no `access_token` in `AsyncStorage`.

What I'm confused about is how to get the token from `AsyncStorage` because it's an asynchronous process. I can't seem to `await` the call in my `App` component i.e. it gives me an error if I try and if I don't `await` it, then I get a `promise`.

How do I implement this using `React Navigation 5`?

Here's my `App` component:

```
const App = () => {

  const authenticatedUser = AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token");
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {
          authenticatedUser !== null || typeof authenticatedUser !== "undefined"
          ? <RootNavigator />
          : <AuthNavigator />
        }
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you tried hooks and async callback for getting token along with combination of some loading state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for getting a token from AsyncStorage like this.

```
const App = () => {

const [loading, setLoading] = usState(true)
const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = usState(false)

useEffect(()=>{async()=>{
  const authenticatedUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token");
  setLoading(false)
  if(authenticatedUser !== null) setAuthenticated(true)
 }},[])

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        { loading &&
         <ActivityIndictor size='small' />
        }
        {
          authenticated && !loading
          ? <RootNavigator />
          : <AuthNavigator />
        }
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you! This works nicely but I do have one question. Because we're using `useEffect()`, this function will be invoked everytime the component mounts/updates. I worry that because `AsyncStorage` operations are `async`, will this not negatively affect the performance of the app?

Comment: Actually this function will work like componentDidMount and will not call on every update as you can see in the useEffect i am passing an array as an argument it means it will render on every update.

Comment: I will also edit this answer and move async operation somewhere else because handling async function in callback of hooks is not the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use some loader. Load data from your AsyncStorage check if the token was valid and refresh if it is not, load user profile and do more your initialization staff. In code you would do this!

```
let Loader=()=>{
const [loadingData, setLoading]= useState(null);
let effect=async ()=>{
    let credentials = await AsyncStorage.getItem(“data”)
    setLoading(credentials||{})
}
useEffect(()=>effect())
If (loadingData===null)
     return <LoadingView/>
return <YourRouter {...{loadingData}}/>
```