# React Native Redux Authentication

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have a redux application which works well with react but I am trying to do the same with a react native app.
The flow of the app is that after successful login, token is stored in async storage and the user is routed to home stack and if user closes the app and reopens it, if there is a valid token in async storage the user is redirected to home stack if not redirected to auth stack.

Please see my code:

#useractions.js

```
import { SET_USER, SET_ERRORS, CLEAR_ERRORS, LOADING_UI, SET_UNAUTHENTICATED, LOADING_USER } from '../types';
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export const loginUser = (userData) => (dispatch) => {
    // dispatch({ type: LOADING_UI });
    axios.post('urllogin', userData)
    .then((res)=> {
        console.warn("res", res)
        setAuthorizationHeader(res.data.token)
        dispatch(getUserData());
        console.warn("successful login")
        // dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS });
        // props.navigation.navigate('Home');
    })
    .catch((err)=> {
        console.warn("error", err)
        dispatch({
            type: SET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.response.data
        })    
    })
}

export const getUserData = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING_USER });
    axios.get('urluserinfo')
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: SET_USER,
            payload: res.data
        })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

}

const setAuthorizationHeader = (token) => {
    const FBIdToken = `Bearer ${token}`
    AsyncStorage.setItem('FBIdToken', FBIdToken);
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = FBIdToken;
}
```

## userReducer.js

```
import { SET_USER, SET_AUTHENTICATED, SET_UNAUTHENTICATED, LOADING_USER } from '../types';

const initialState = {
    authenticated: false,
    loading: false,
    credentials: {},
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case SET_AUTHENTICATED:
            return {
                ...state,
                authenticated: true
            };
        case SET_UNAUTHENTICATED:
            return initialState;
        case SET_USER:
            return {
                authenticated: true,
                loading: false,
                ...action.payload
            };
        case LOADING_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            }
        default:
            return state;

    }
}
```

## App.js

```
let authenticated;
const token = AsyncStorage.getItem('FBIdToken');
if(token){
  authenticated = true;
} else {
  authenticated = false;
}

    export default function App() {

      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          { authenticated ? (
                <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} /> } >
                <Drawer.Screen name='MainTab' component={MainTabScreen} />
                <Drawer.Screen name='SupportScreen' component={SupportScreen} />
                <Drawer.Screen name='BookmarkScreen' component={BookmarkScreen} />
              </Drawer.Navigator>
          ) : 
          <RootStackScreen /> 
          }
        </NavigationContainer>
        </Provider>
      );
    }
```

## signInScreen.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loginUser } from '../redux/actions/userActions';

class SignInScreen extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            errors: {},
            check_textInputChange: false,
        secureTextEntry: true,
        isValidUser: true,
        isValidPassword: true,
        }
    }


    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if(nextProps.UI.errors) {
            this.setState({ errors: nextProps.UI.errors });
        }
    }

    onChangeText = name => (text) => {
        this.setState({ [name]: text });
      }

     loginHandle = () => {
        const userData = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        };
        console.warn(userData)
        this.props.loginUser(userData);
    };

    render() {
        const { email, password } = this.state;
    return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
         <Animatable.View 
         animation="fadeInUpBig"
         style={styles.footer}
         >
             <Text style={styles.text_footer}>Email</Text>
             <View style={styles.action}>
                 <FontAwesome
                 name="user-o"
                 color="#05375a"
                 size={20}
                 />
                 <TextInput
                 placeholder="Your email"
                 style={styles.textInput}
                 autoCapitalize="none"
                //  onChangeText={(val) => this.textInputChange(val)}
                onChangeText={this.onChangeText("email")}
                value={email}
                //  onEndEditing={(e) => handleValidUser(e.nativeEvent.text)}
                 />
             </View>        
             <Text style={[styles.text_footer, {
                 marginTop: 35
             }]}>Password</Text>
             <View style={styles.action}>
                 <Feather
                 name="lock"
                 color="#05375a"
                 size={20}
                 />
                 <TextInput
                 placeholder="Your Password"
                 secureTextEntry={this.state.secureTextEntry ? true: false}
                 style={styles.textInput}
                 autoCapitalize="none"
                //  onChangeText={(val) => this.handlePasswordChange(val)}
                onChangeText={this.onChangeText("password")}
                value={password}
                 />
             </View>
             <View style={styles.button}>
             <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.signIn}
                 onPress={() => {this.loginHandle()}}>
                 <LinearGradient
                 colors={['#08d4c4', '#01ab9d']}
                 style={styles.signIn}
                 >
                     <Text style={[styles.textSign, {
                         color: '#fff'
                     } 
                    ]}>Sign In</Text>
                 </LinearGradient>
                 </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
         </Animatable.View >
     </View>
    )
                    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    user: state.user,
    UI: state.UI,
})

const mapActionsToProps = {
    loginUser
}

export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps )(SignInScreen);
```

Currently I am unable to check if the user has a valid token in asyncstorage and present the user with either home stack or auth stack and how to redirect the user to the home stack after a successful login.

Please help.

Comment: My answer to this question will work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61665360/react-navigation-5-auth-flow/61666684#61666684

Comment: I tried, but it did not work

Comment: Any specific reason because this is not works?

Comment: It does not set authenticated to true and my asyncstorage returns {"40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null}. Please can you send a working example of ur reducer and actions so I can compare

Comment: Your Asyncstorage returning a promise you have to resolve that promise then it will authenticated to true.

Comment: Pls how can I do this

Comment: Make a snack on expo and share to me i will fix it.