# How to persist Login with token?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Hello there I have created dotnet core web api for login and register but in the app after refresh it always tries to log in again. Since I am new to react native I could not apply solutions to my project. I use redux and here is my action :

```
export const signin = (email, password) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const response = await fetch(
      'http://localhost:5000/api/user/login',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: email,
          password: password,

        }),
      }
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
    }

    const resData = await response.json();
    console.log(resData);
    dispatch({ type: SINGIN, token: resData.token, userId: resData.id });
    saveDataToStorage(resData.token);
  };
};

const saveDataToStorage = (token, userId) => {
  AsyncStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify({
    token: token,
  })
  );
};
```

And here is my navigator with react navigation 5 :

```
export const Navigator = () => {
    const [userToken, setUserToken] = React.useState(null);
    const userData = AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');

    const authContext = React.useMemo(() => {
        return {
            signIn: () => {
                setUserToken(userData);
            },
            singnUp: () => {
                setUserToken(userData);
            },
            signOut: () => {
                setUserToken(null);
            },
        };
    }, [userData]);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <RootStackScreen userToken={userToken} />
            </NavigationContainer>
        </AuthContext.Provider >
    );
};
```

As I said I could not find a way to apply solutions that I found. Thank you for you help.

Comment: You already persisting token in `AsyncStorage ` then what's the problem?

Comment: but be careful `AsyncStorage ` has all of its action `async` so you have to use `promise or async/await`

Comment: it is still asking for log in after refresh. Should I write a function outside of the navigator or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure all of your actions with AsyncStorage should be async(Use promise or async/await).

Then follow this to implement the authentication flow of your application.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow

My this answer will be helpful for you.

[React Navigation 5 Auth Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61665360/react-navigation-5-auth-flow/61666684#61666684)

Comment: I am trying to apply stack over flow solution to my RootStackScreen but in userEffect authenticatedUser is null and shows something like this : {"_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null}

Comment: I cant find anyone tried to resolve. its all const authenticatedUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData'); and setting the state true. I am doing the same but nothing happens its always false.

Comment: make a snack on expo with this issue and I will fix it.

Comment: I made it mate thank you very much for you support.